Passing data from a component to children inside a layout
Going through the tutorial for NextJS, their provided the following Layout
import SideNav from '@/app/ui/dashboard/sidenav';
 
export default function Layout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {

  return (
    <div className="flex h-screen flex-col md:flex-row md:overflow-hidden">
      <div className="w-full flex-none md:w-64">
        <SideNav />
      </div>
      <div className="flex-grow p-6 md:overflow-y-auto md:p-12">{children}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

It seems like a reasonable structure. I want to share the same sideNav across the entire application. The only thing I can't figure out is how to pass data to the children from the sideNav.
I will likely have some app-level actions in my sideNav, and based on user action, I will want to pass data to the children.
For example, changing between different dashboard data sources.
Is that possible or in the case this structure is just not the right one?
Reference: https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/creating-layouts-and-pages

Use a global state management system with Context API, redux, or any other state management solution you prefer.
This way you can perform the desired action based on different action states.
import React, { createContext, useReducer, useContext } from 'react';

const GlobalContext = createContext();

const StateProvider=({children,reducer,store})=><GlobalContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer,store)}>{children}</GlobalContext.Provider>

const useStateValue=()=>useContext(GlobalContext)




ChatGPT generated code isn't allowed here.

I made a thread about – “When deciding between useState and useReducer in React”
You may check it out here   https://x.com/lassiecoder/status/1838531218196824251
